# Thought IE 8 would interprete box modell correctly... am I missing something?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, css

I thought IE 8's way of displaying stuff is now regarding the W3C Box Model but just recognized it doesn't. I want to use a global wrapper for my content that is effectively 772 pixel wide (trying to optimize for the viewport of a 800 pixel wide screen) but gives an inner padding of 20 pixels each side. Wouldn't that have to look like the following snippet?

```
 #content   { 
        padding: 20px; 
        width: 772px; 
        left: 50%; 
        margin-left: -386px; 
 }
/* IE 7   */ *:first-child+html #content { width: 732px; }
```

Somehow, it doesn't... Please help me! I'm totally confused of this whole IE thing. I thought the definitions for an IE 8 have to be set just as they are for regular browsers but again, padding-values expand the width of the element. What am I missing? Could a DTD be the problem? I use transitional type as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to center the wrapper to the viewport? Does this work:

```
 #content   { 
         padding: 20px; 
         width: 772px; 
         margin: auto;
         -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

As far as I know, the standard sizing model is the very counterintuitive content model, and you have to set the `box-sizing` rule to get it to be box-model.

http://quirksmode.org/css/box.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, Anthony! The center positioning was no problem but rather the exact width of the element. Really didn't know about this "box-sizing" thing at all, but it helps out perfectly!